# How can I predict whether the moment or product or inertia is zero by observation only?

Tags: moment-of-inertia

There are a lot of questions in my (first year) lecture notes where the instructor uses moment of inertia tensor to perform calculations involving angular momentum. And he directly makes a statement such as *Ixy =0* ... I have no idea how he reached that conclusion just by observing and neither does he clarify one bit.

Is there any symmetry consideration to be taken into account? I know that say, if an object lies in the xz plane its product of inertia *Ixy* and *Iyz* will be zero but how to know that for the image file I've uploaded?[image]

Here the only term that remains in calculation is *Izx* while all of *Ixx* , *Iyy* , *Izz* , *Iyz* , *Ixy* turn out to be zero. HOW??

Answer (score -1):

For any 3D body it is always possible to find 3 mutually orthogonal axes to which the off diagonal terms are zero.

In your example that is not done and so the off diagonal terms are not necessarily zero.

$I_{\rm zx} = \int zx\,dm$ where you are adding all the contributions of masses $dm$ at position (x,y,z).

[image]

With the axes as chosen in your example (left hand diagram) that integral has a net negative value because the contributions from negative regions $A$ and $C$ are larger than that from the positive regions $B$ and $D$.

If the axes had been chosen along the principal axes the off diagonal value are all zero.
In the right hand diagram positive regions $B$ and $D$ contribute an equal amount to the integral as negative regions $A$ and $C$.